# ECMAScript 6 internet explorer 11 - Do I have to re-do my code?

Tags: javascript, math, internet-explorer-11

The Javascript code to find missing number doesn't work in IE 11 but works in Chrome and Firefox. I just learned that IE 11 doesn't support EMCA 6.0

Need to redo this line   `for(var i=Math.min(...arr); i<Math.max(...arr); i++){`

```
var str = "1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21;22;23;24;25;26;27;28;29;30;31;32;33;34;35;36;37;38;39;40;41;42;43;44;45;46;47;48;49;50;51;52;53;54;55;56;57;58;59;60;61;62;63;64;65;66;67;68;69;70;71;72;75;76;77;78;79;80;81;82;83;84;85;86;87;88;89;90;91;92;1001;1002;1003;1004;1005;1006;1007;73;";
function getMissingNumber(str){
  var arr = str.split(/\;/);
  var missingNum = [];
  for(var i=Math.min(...arr); i<Math.max(...arr); i++){
     if(arr.indexOf(i.toString()) === -1){
       missingNum.push(i);
       if(i){
       alert(i);return; }
     }
  }
  return missingNum;
}
console.log(getMissingNumber(str));
//alert(getMissingNumber(str));
```

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=es6

Everything marked as not compatible in the given link must be redo in order to work in IE11 or use a transpiler

Comment: Look into Babel: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/

Comment: …or if you don't want to use a transpiler, just use `apply` in the two cases where you used ES6 spread syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some answers suggest you to transpile your code to ES5 (with babel) and it is a working solution.

So if your project is big and you use lot of ES6 features that are not supported in IE11 (and you want to support IE11) then babel and/or other tools are worth checking (webpack, parcelJs, etc).

**But** if you just need to make this code IE11/ES5 compliant you can just call `Math.min` with `apply`, like this ;

`Math.min.apply(null, array)`

Example with spread operator (...) and apply : 
https://repl.it/@Benoit_Vasseur/spread-operator-to-ES5-for-array

Apply documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: I change the code to for(var i=Math.min.apply(null, arr); i<Math.max.apply(null, arr); i++) and it works in Chrome and Firefox. IE 11 is still messed up.

Comment: for(var i=Math.min.apply(Math, arr); i<Math.max.apply(Math, arr); i++) worked for me. Thanks @Tchiize